# An Approximation involving the Exponential Integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods

Define for real $x > 0$ the function:
\begin{equation}
F(x)= 1 + x e^{x} Ei(-x),
\end{equation}
where $Ei(x)$ is the exponential integral. I found in a physics papers (Amaldi, Fluctuations in Calorimetry Measurements) the following approximation for $0 < x < 0.3$:
\begin{equation}
F(x) \approx e^x [1+x \log(x/1.526)].
\end{equation}
Amaldi states without justification nor reference that this approximation is valid at 10% in the given range. Does anyone has any idea of this formula?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That approximation just comes from an asymptotic approximation for the [incomplete $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).
We have:

> $$ F(x)\,e^{-x} = e^{-x}+x\,\Gamma(0,x) =  \color{red}{1+\left(-1+\gamma+\log(x)\right)x}\color{blue}{-\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{12}x^3-\frac{1}{72}x^4+\ldots}$$

where the blue part is the Taylor series at $x=0$ of an entire function, hence a fast-converging series for any $x$ in the given range.

Comment: Dear Jack, now I see where that mysterious formulas came from! Only I guess you took all the terms in the expansion of $\Gamma(0,x)$ with the opposite sign. The right expression should be so $1 + x (\log x - (1-\gamma)) - x^2/2 + x^3/12 -x^4 /72 + ....$. Thank you very very very much for invaluable help!

Comment: @MauryBarbato: right, now fixed. You're welcome!